# AJAX data.Success returning false when there is data in response

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the [JQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) but having an issue with IE 11 where "data.Success" is coming back false eventhough there is JSON in the response as evidenced by tracing the network traffic with IE Developer Tools.

I am seeing a successful initial AJAX POST to  /NewClubOpeningTool/ProcessCompose/ with a hydrated JSON response, yet data.Success is false.

**Response:**

```
{"Success":true,"ViewMode":"Prospects","DraftOrSentViewMode":"Draft","NewClubId":21}
```

Works fine in FF and Chrome.

Any ideas, why this is occurring and what I can try?

**//The form setup**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ProcessCompose", "NewClubOpeningTool", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "update_panel" }, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data", id="ComposeForm" }))
```

**//The controller action that handles the form submit**

```
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ProcessCompose(NewClubInviteComposeEmailViewModel compose, IEnumerable<int> Recipients)
        {
            [...]

            return Json(new { Success = success }, "text/json", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }




 //This code lives in the view that has the AJAX form
 $(document).ready(function () {

        /***********************************************************
            Initialize the JQuery Form object
            This is how we are able to upload stuff via an AJAX form
        *************************************************************/

        var options = { 
            type:'post',
            data: $('#ComposeForm').serializeArray(),
            datatype: 'json',
            url: '/NewClubOpeningTool/ProcessCompose/',
            success: function (data) {
            if (data.Success) {
                alert('Success! We have data.Success!');
                $(".dialog").remove();
                $("#divInviteContentArea").load("/NewClubOpeningTool/InviteEmail?clubId=" + data.NewClubId + "&viewMode=" + data.ViewMode + "&draftOrSentViewMode=" + data.DraftOrSentViewMode);
            } else {
                alert('Error! We do not have data.Success!');
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert('Error: ' + textStatus);
        }                   
    }; 
    $('#ComposeForm').ajaxForm(options);
        /*************************************************************
        Prevent the AJAX form from submitting twice
        **************************************************************/
        $("#ComposeForm").submit(function (e) {

             e.preventDefault();

             return false;


        });
    });
```

Comment: `new { Success = success },`... do you have a variable named `success`? If so, what's in it? If it's a false-y value, then you're going to say "Success = failed!" anyways. Perhaps you'd have more luck with `Success = true` instead.

Comment: Response is: {"Success":true,"ViewMode":"Prospects","DraftOrSentViewMode":"Draft","NewClubId":21}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is correct but you made a small mistake:
ie:-

change `datatype:'json'` to `dataType:'json'` its **T** (caps) in ajax call.

Comment: That was it. Thanks for your keen eye!

Comment: Its not actually my keen eyes, But I have strucked in the same issue for two days....!

Comment: That sounds awful! Thanks